# How would i be able to change the AdapterName value in this code?

Tags: c++

```
DWORD GetAdaptersInfo(PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo, PULONG pOutBufLen)
{
    pAdapterInfo->AdapterName
    return GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, pOutBufLen)
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the `AdapterName` value in `pAdapterInfo` and return a new `PIP_ADAPTER_INFO`?

Comment: I think is can be changed, but not advisable since it will be tough to manage

Comment: What are these types?

Answer (score 0):

I should mention that I have no idea what `Adaptor` you are dealing with. However, in spite of my ignorance of the details I can tell you that this cannot work (obvious errors fixed and assumed `AdapterName` is a string):

```
DWORD GetAdaptersInfo(PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo, PULONG pOutBufLen)
{
    pAdapterInfo->AdapterName = "foo";
    return GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, pOutBufLen);
}
```

You are calling the function recursively and there is no end to that recursion. Instead you can do something like this:

```
DWORD GetAdaptersInfo(PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo, PULONG pOutBufLen,STRING_t newName)
{
    pAdapterInfo->AdapterName = newName;
    return GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, pOutBufLen);
}
```

where I assume a `DWORD GetAdaptersInfo(PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo, PULONG pOutBufLen)` exists and can be called.

But note that depeding on `PID_ADAPTER_INFO` being a value type or reference type, the caller of `GetAdapterInfo` has no chance to notice that the `AdapterInfo` he gets is coming from a different name, because (if it is a value) his `pAdapterInfo` will still hold the old name.